# how do i split and rearrange from 1 file to another?

Tags: python

From this file-

File1:

```
Hello 123 th3is i1s
One the -76 files  -8.43
```

To this:

File2:

```
"Hello th3is i1s One the files"
```

And this:

File3:

```
123 -76 -8.43
```

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regular expression

```py
import re

s = """Hello 123 th3is i1s
One the -76 files  -8.43"""

file_1 = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\d*[a-zA-Z]+', s, re.M) # ['Hello', 'th3is', 'i1s', 'One', 'the', 'files']
file_2 = re.findall(r'-*\d+\.*\d+', s, re.M) # ['123', '-76', '-8.43']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can split whitespace delimited tokens in a line-oriented file and distinguish numbers in order to isolate one from the other:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    numbers = []
    words = []
    with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
        with open('file3.txt', 'w') as file3:
            for line in map(str.strip, file1):
                for token in line.split():
                    try:
                        float(token)
                        numbers.append(token)
                    except ValueError:
                        words.append(token)
            print(' '.join(words), file=file2)
            print(' '.join(numbers), file=file3)
```

The outputs to file2 and file3 are as per the requirements in the original question

Answer (score -1):

Read the file by words, and populate lists with words and numbers

```
words = []
numbers = []
with open('input.txt','r') as file:  
    for line in file:     
        for word in line.split():
            try:
                numbers.append(float(word))
            except:
                words.append(word)
```

After that write the content of two lists into two separate files

Comment: `"-8.43".isnumeric()` -> `False`